# Oracle SQL "SELECT DATE from DATETIME field "

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I have field REPORTDATE (DATETIME).
In SQL Developer i can see its value in this format

`29.10.2013 17:08:08`

I found that in order to do the select of just a DATE I need to execute this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE (REPORTDATE, 'DD.MON.YYYY') AS my_date
FROM TABLE1
```

but it returns `0RA-01843: not a valid month`

I want result to return only 29.10.2013

Comment: is it ok for you ; select trunc (to_Date('10.04.2012 14:56:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) from  dual

Comment: What is the **data type** of `REPORTDATE`. Is it a DATE or STRING?

Comment: its DATETIME in the database. I added information now

Comment: It's a column, not a field.

Comment: @newuserua_ext it is not OK because it returns 29.10.2013 00:00:00 this is not solution

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> TO_DATE (REPORTDATE, 'DD.MON.YYYY')

This makes no sense. You are converting a date into a date again. You use **TO_DATE** to convert a string literal into **DATE**.

> I want result to return only 29.10.2013

You could use **TRUNC** to truncate the time element. If you want to use this value for DATE calculations, you could use it directly.

For example,

```
SQL> select TRUNC(SYSDATE) dt FROM DUAL;

DT
---------
12-MAR-15
```

To display in a particular format, you could use **TO_CHAR** and proper **FORMAT MASK**.

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual;

DT
----------
12.03.2015

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you this is solution. May I ask you additionnal question I am trying to do the group by with this date column but not succeed please look "SELECT to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS MYDATE, COUNT(*) from TABLE1
GROUP BY MYDATE" it returns Invalid identifier

Comment: please help me with this additional thing I want to now group on that column but it returns error "invalid identifier"

Comment: `GROUP BY to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') `

Comment: Also, this might be useful to understand nls settings, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28298920/3989608

Comment: thank you and one more thing (last I promise). If I want to do the comparation for example I want to see dates later than "09.11.2013" but it returns me as result also and 30.10.2013            Expression I used was:    SELECT to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), COUNT(*) from TABLE
where to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')>'09.11.2013'
 
GROUP BY to_char(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')

Comment: its called "Oracle SQL comparison of DATEs returns wrong result"

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
SELECT trunc(REPORTDATE, 'DD') AS my_date
FROM TABLE1
```

This will not change the type of the returning object, only truncates everything below "day" level.

If you are ok with returning a String, then you can just do:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(REPORTDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS my_date
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: This is not solution. It returns "29.10.2013 00:00:00"

Answer (score -1):

Try this code snipppet:

```
 cast(datetimevariable as date)
```

Comment: This is for SQL Server (and possibly others), not Oracle.