# Get only date in oracle

Tags: oracle, date

1. How do i strip everything else and get just the date:

I have the date in this format

```
2018-01-27T00:00:00
```

I should get in `MM/DD/YYYY` Format.

My Result should be `01/27/2018`.

2. How do I remove all the special characters in $185,000.32 and just get **Amount** as 185000.32 
   Note: **Amount** is a field in table of Number Datatype.

Comment: Duplicate of [Oracle SQL "SELECT DATE from DATETIME field "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004960/oracle-sql-select-date-from-datetime-field)

Answer (score 0):

**1**

a) if you have datetime as string and want output as string:

```
select to_char(to_date(substr('2018-01-27T00:00:00',1,10),'yyyy-mm-dd'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
from dual;
```

b) if you have variable/column of date type and want output as string:

```
select to_char( your_variable_or_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY' )
from dual;
```

**2** if you have value as string

```
select 
    to_number( '$185,000.32', 
    'L9G999G999G999G999G999D99', 
    'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'' NLS_CURRENCY=''$''' ) 
from dual;
```

or with regexp get result value as string

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE( '$185,000.32', '[^-0123456789\.]', '' ) 
from dual;
```