# SQLDATE function SQL Error [936] [42000]: ORA-00936: missing expression¶

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DATE(eoa.DATETIME) AS Date_OF_Alert,
        COUNT(*) AS Num
 FROM   ECMS_ONLINE_ALERTS eoa
 GROUP BY DATE(eoa.DATETIME)
 ORDER BY eoa.DATETIME
```

this my sql function i am getting error like

SQL Error [936] [42000]: ORA-00936: missing expression¶

how to resolve it

Comment: Hint: DATETIME is a very poor choice for a column name as it's a reserved word in most RDBMS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL "SELECT DATE from DATETIME field "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004960/oracle-sql-select-date-from-datetime-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see: [Oracle SQL "SELECT DATE from DATETIME field "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004960/oracle-sql-select-date-from-datetime-field)

use:

```
SELECT TRUNC(eoa.DATETIME) AS Date_OF_Alert,
        COUNT(*) AS Num
 FROM   ECMS_ONLINE_ALERTS eoa
 GROUP BY TRUNC(eoa.DATETIME)
 ORDER BY TRUNC(eoa.DATETIME)
```