# how to convert YYYYMMDD to DD-Mon-YYYY in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to convert the date from **YYYYMMDD** to **DD-Mon-YYYY** in Oracle, but `to_char` or `to_Date` is not working. Can you please advise?

`select to_date(20150324,'DD-Mon-YY') from dual;
select to_char(20150324,'DD-Mon-YY') from dual;`

I get an error message saying: `- ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

Comment: ["TO_DATE converts [characters\] .. to a value of DATE datatype."](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) - see what the function does, and how the parameters are used, for starters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [change dd-MMM-yy date format to yyyy-MM-dd format in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298838/change-dd-mmm-yy-date-format-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-oracle)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this combination of `to_char` and `to_date`:

```
select to_char (to_date('20150324','YYYYMMDD'), 'DD-Mon-YY') from dual;
```

Your mistake was, that you used the wrong date pattern. Additionally it's recommended to add`''`, though it worked without them in this case.

Check [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/1365).

Comment: @Trinimon, the error is not due to the missing quotes, though it would error out for sure. But the posted error is due to mismatch in the format mask.

Comment: Yes, you're right: quotes were missing but it worked without `''` as well. Though I think there was an implicit type conversion which is not really recommended. I'll add a note on the format in the text (fixed it in the Fiddle but missed to mention it above)

Comment: don't you end up with a char column and not a date column doing this?

Comment: @mLstudent33: a date column has no format at all. The format is a matter of date representation. My code above converts the representation '20150324' into the representation '24-Mar-15', intermediately using a date for the conversion. Hope that helps :)