# Oracle hour format (syntax)

Tags: date, oracle11g, to-date

Maybe this question could have been awnsered in nother post, but I can not find anything similair to my problem (or I can not see the solution).

My question is as follow:

I work in an Oracle11g database and I would like to pass my to_date value to hour value. I wrote it like this:

```
insert into OPENINGSTIJDEN (id, dag, openingstijd, sluitingstijd, winkel_nummer)
values(2, 'dinsdag', to_date('09:00:00','hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('18:00:00','hh24:mi:ss'), 10);
```

My results are this

[image]

I only get dates like 01-03-15. Is it my to_date? I can not find the solution on the web

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to change the date display options in SQLDeveloper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: The format that you see by default is your locale-specific NLS settings. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28298920/3989608